# Where is the official documentation for /etc/fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab

I want to start editing my `/etc/fstab` file more comfortably and not rely on random forums anymore. But wherever I go, I see very scarce info about it. I can nowhere find a webpage that, for example, explains all of the options available. So, who owns the `fstab` file, what program uses it, and where can I find the official documentation for it from its creator?

Specifically, I want to understand the difference between `none`, `mem` and `tmpfs` devices (the first field). I know, I can probably google it and eventually find the answer, but as I said, I don't want to do it anymore, I want to go full-geek mode and read from the official resources.

**EDIT:** Quick answer: The difference should be only in the string (the name) and should only matter to systemd that reads the file when mounting filesystems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for system files such as `fstab` is (almost always) on your machine. In this instance [`man fstab`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) will answer your question - up to a point:

> The first field (`fs_spec`). This field describes the block  special  device  or  remote  filesystem  to  be mounted.
>
> [...] For filesystems with no storage, any string can be used, and will show up in `df`(1) output, for example.  Typical usage is `proc` for procfs; `mem`, `none`, or `tmpfs` for tmpfs.

You've just mentioned in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694829/where-is-the-official-documentation-for-etc-fstab/694836#comment1313676_694829) that you want to create a `tmpfs` entry. Here's [an example](https://superuser.com/a/1387876/332907) of one for `/mnt/mytmpfs`:

```
tmpfs /mnt/mytmpfs tmpfs nosuid,nodev,noatime 0 0
```

Don't forget to create the directory yourself (`mkdir /mnt/mytmpfs`).

Comment: Thanks. However, it still doesn't explain the **difference** between these 3 options

Comment: The difference between which options? `mem`, `none`, `tmpfs`? There is no difference except the string itself. That's what the documentation means when it says, "_any string can be used_"

Comment: Really? wow. I guess that at least that string itself is stored somewhere since findmnt reads it correctly. Anyway, I believe you. Thanks lol

Comment: @donaastor the documentation for `findmnt` (see `man findmnt`) explains that it can look in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thank you agian. I thought it would be so, but thanks for checking. Also, please allow me to add the "quick answer" to my question, I won't address you this time if you don't like it

Comment: That's not how these sites work. Questions go in the question, and answers go in an answer. It's different to many forums where you're expected to write "solved" it whatever in the question title

Comment: @donaastor your "quick answer" doesn't look like an answer to the main question. Otherwise, the question may be considered as "not focused" since it looks like you're actually asking 2 questions at the same time: 1) the documentation of `fstab`, 2) the difference of the string.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, fstab has its own [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) `man fstab` which describes the file and its structure but if you want details about the mount options, you should look at [mount man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) which describes supported mount options for filesystems and also links to other man pages (like [tmpfs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html)) for filesystem specific options. You should also look at the very end of the man page where it links/mentions other related topics like [proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) that can help you answer your question.

> who owns the fstab file

Nobody, but in depending on your distribution it usually has to be own by somebody so n Fedora it is owned by the `setup` package:

```
Description  : The setup package contains a set of important system configuration and
             : setup files, such as passwd, group, and profile.
```

> what program uses it

Whoever wants to use it. `mount` use it if you don't specify both source (device) and target (mount point). systemd uses it during boot to mount filesystems like `/home`. UDisks uses it to find mount points and options for devices when mounting a device from a file browser.

> where can I find the official documentation for it from its creator

Other than the man page mentioned above, there isn't any single document that would cover everything. At least not from a "creator" of fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type `man <topic>` into any search engine.

Here the `<topic>` being [fstab](https://man7.org/index.html) for example.

This more often than not produces what is required. Of course the official documentation that matches OS, vendor and hardware should always be consulted if there is any question of accuracy or relevance in the results.

Reputable results will come from sites like [man7.org](https://man7.org/index.html) and [die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/).

Benefits over console:

- Web pages will likely include links to related topics, e.g. mount. Which will allow you to learn about related topics.
- It can be more convieninent than a console man page.
- In some systems man pages are missing to conserve space.

Possible drawbacks:

Just be careful as some tools change over time and may not match the ones you are using. I find the web hosted man pages tend to refer to recent versions.

Some packages have forks or separate implementations between platforms (Intel/ARM), OS (BSD/Linux/etc) or distribution (RedHat/Debian) so for some commands the options and usage may differ. Again check the source is relevant.

Some systems have bundelled tools 'shrunk' into a single single command e.g. [busybox](https://busybox.net/).

Always check the man page you are looking at matches the command and system you are running it on. You can often check this with `-v` or `--version` appended to the command line.